# How to catch uncaught exceptions in Orleans

Tags: c#, orleans

Whenever exception occurs in orlean grain, it silently gets deactivated without any log message, so it has become very problematic to find what is going wrong.

Please help us to know how to log uncaught exception in Orleans.

We checked whole Orleans documentation, but it is not mentioned how to change this behavior.

Comment: Have you tried Grain Call Filters? They can execute code both before and after a grain call. Here is the doc: https://dotnet.github.io/orleans/docs/grains/interceptors.html

Comment: I'm curious -- how did you become aware that an exception was occurring if there is no evidence in logs?

Comment: Each grain has a state associated with it, when a new grain is created, it's state is reinitialized.